# Couldn't load type 'HomePage.aspx.cs'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am implementing a small website that will take input from the user and interact with a database in c# but the problem is that the code behind (the code in the .aspx.cs file) doesn't read any element in the .aspx file,though I did assigned the inherit attribute in the directive of the .aspx file to be the .aspx.cs file .

## This is the HomePage.aspx file

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="HomePage.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="lbl_username" runat="server" Text="Username:   "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="lbl_password" runat="server" Text="Password:   "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="login" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## This is the HomePage.aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


    public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void login(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("loginProcedure", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string username = txt_username.Text;
            string password = txt_password.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username));

            SqlParameter name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            name.Value = password;

            // output parm
            SqlParameter count = cmd.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int);
            count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            if (count.Value.ToString().Equals("1"))
            {

                Response.Write("Passed");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting that error couldn't load type 'HomePage.aspx.cs' , So how can I do handle such event ?

Comment: Clean and rebuild. Delete stuff in your Obj folder too.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the class name not the full file name for the inherits attribute

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="HomePage" %>
```

Comment: @user3423255 try clean and rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `Inherits` property should not contain the file extension. Here's what [the Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) says about the Inherits property:

> **Inherits**
>
> Defines a code-behind class for the page to inherit. This can be any
>   class derived from the Page class. This attribute is used with the
>   CodeFile attribute, which contains the path to the source file for the
>   code-behind class. The Inherits attribute is case-sensitive when using
>   C# as the page language, and case-insensitive when using Visual Basic
>   as the page language.

So the `CodeBehind` (or `CodeFile` for Web Site projects) attribute should have the file path, while the Inherits attribute contains just the class name. Try replacing `Inherits="HomePage.aspx.cs"` with `Inherits="HomePage"`, including the namespace if applicable.